# How to disable (completely) and enable any mouse listener in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, mousewheel

I have a strange question: How to disable all mouse events (`mousewheel`, `click`, `hover` etc.) on button click and after a timeout, for example 1s, enable them again?

First I've tried with the unbind/bind functions but there is a strange bug with the scroll events on Apple Magic mouse. Than I came up with this:

```
$("* ... or some selector").on("scroll click ...", function(){
  return false;
});
```

Its'not very pretty but it's work. The problem is that I don't know how to re-enable the events after one second for example?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's not a solution...the mouse events will be still fireing

Comment: You can use `off()` to remove the event handlers if they were bound with `on()`

Comment: I've tried that also, but it doesn't work...works same as the unbind/bind method. Is there a way to "restart" the events listere?

Comment: Nope, you have to bind them again, and it can be done easier with named functions that are referenced etc, but there's no magic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently probably using [`anonymous functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Defining_functions). If you actually name your function, you can always reinitialize your event listener later:

```
var myMethod = function () {
    // does something
}

$('my selector').on('my event', myMethod)
```

As for the one second: [`timeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)